# How to access a remote repository using git bash windows (permission denied, public key - error)

Tags: windows, bash, ssh, git, public-key

Im connecting for the first time to a remote git server using bash.

These were my steps:

1. Loaded the existing key in PUTTYgen
2. Saved the .ppk private key and then exported to my .ssh as OpenSSH under the name id_rsa
3. then I added the .ppk to PAGEANT
4. On PUTTY, I entered the server IP I want to connect on port 22
   and then went to SSH/AUTH in order to enter the path for the private key> C:\Users\Fabio.ssh\id_rsa
5. Still in PUTTY, I went back to sessions, selected the IP, clicked on load, and then on open
   (things then loaded as if I could connect)
6. then on git bash i entered

`$ ssh -i "C:\users\path\to\id_rsa" "username@ip"`

But at the end of this process I keep being asked on git bash for password. 3 times, actually and then -permission denied(public key).

Also, I add a variable GIT_SSH in the system pointing to PLINK.

What am I missing here, please?

Comment: No, I dont. I just need to access the repo, but with no success

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSH to github using CygWin doesn't work](http://superuser.com/questions/1043367/ssh-to-github-using-cygwin-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to specify the private key. It is usually `id_rsa` and not `id_rsa.pub`

```
$ ssh -i "C:\users\path\to\id_rsa" "username@ip"
```

I have not tried this, am on Linux.

Comment: I tried that now and I got same results. only this time I got also a key_load_public: invalid format before they asked me to enter the passphrase

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the private key in OpenSSH format from PuTTYgen, not just rename the PPK one. It will not work.

Also the `IdentityFile` points to the private key, not the public one.

Comment: I just followed you instructions.
1. Loaded the existing key in PUTTYgen, 
2. Saved the .ppk private key and then exported to my .ssh as OpenSSH under the name id_rsa
3. then I added the .ppk to PAGEANT
4. On PUTTY, I entered the server IP I want to connect on port 22
and then went to SSH/AUTH in order to enter the path for the private key> C:\Users\Fabio\.ssh\id_rsa
5. Still in PUTTY, I went back to sessions, selected the IP, clicked on load, and then on open
>>> things loaded as if I could connect

6. then on git bash i entered $ ssh -i "C:\users\path\to\id_rsa" "username@ip"

Comment: But still asking for password 3 times and then -permission denied(public key).